# How do I increment row in mysql at each iteration of a"for" loop?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want my little script to take a link that i have already inserted into the database, get therelevent text from that webpage and insert it into a different column on that same row. Then do it again on the next row. I am getting this "Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string" error but Im not sure how to represent the row number correctly. Heres what i have so far.

***UPDATE*** Ok guys I appreciate your help. I think I unclear about this. The error message says it on the line that says `$query1 = "$conn, SELECT adlink, key  FROM usedcars WHERE key = $x";`
Or at least, thats what its saying right now. I have tried all the solutions suggested, and so far I just get a bunch of other errors.

```
for ($y=1;$y=1201;$y++)
    {
    $x = 1;

    $query1 = "$conn, SELECT adlink, key  FROM usedcars WHERE key = $x";

    $query2 = "$conn, INSERT INTO usedcars (adtext), VALUES ($final_text) WHERE key = $x";

    $link_result = mysqli_query($query1);

    $text_holder = file_get_contents($link_result);
    $final_text = parse_array($text_holder, "postingBody", "<!-- .posting -->");

    mysqli_query($query2);
    echo "<font size='18' color='#FFFF00'>Placing text from $link_result into database</font><br>"; 
    $x++;
    }
```

I know its probably something simple...Im just not as smart as you guys.

Comment: Why do you insert WHERE? Never seen this before.

Comment: Saw it here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp  @SergeyScopin

Comment: `WHERE` is used to filter existing results.

Comment: why not consolidate all of your input first before inserting the data?

Comment: That would just fry my brain. I would have to loop through the rows to get the links, then put the text in an array, then loop through the rows again to put the text in row that corresponds to each link? Im getting a headache just thinking about it. Id rather just loop through one time to get what I need, do what i got to do with it, then put the new stuff in its column on that same row. This way, when the loop is done, the whole thing is done. Just seems easier @Semi-Friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `$query1 = "$conn, SELECT adlink, key  FROM usedcars WHERE key = $x";` and pass it to `mysqli_query()` , the `$conn` is assumed as a string and it tries to use `$conn` as string.Thats why the error is coming.

try this -

```
$query1 = "SELECT adlink, key  FROM usedcars WHERE key = $x";

$query2 = "UPDATE usedcars (adtext), VALUES ($final_text) WHERE key = $x";

$link_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
```

Comment: That seemed to have taken care of that. Thank you! But now its telling me my final_text variable is undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: add a check for that.

Answer (score 1):

**first check whether all fields with `key = $x` exists**

use `update` instead of `insert`

`WHERE` is used to filter existing results as said by @Eliel not to add a new one...

```
$query1 = "$conn, SELECT adlink, key  FROM usedcars WHERE key = $x";

$query2 = "$conn, UPDATE usedcars (adtext), VALUES ($final_text) WHERE key = $x";

$link_result = mysqli_query($query1);
```

if want to add a new one use:

```
$query1 = "$conn, SELECT adlink, key  FROM usedcars WHERE key = $x";

$query2 = "$conn, INSERT INTO usedcars (adtext,***,***) VALUES ($final_text,***,***)"; // provide all necessary fields

$link_result = mysqli_query($query1);
```

Comment: Thank you! I have added the parenthesis...@Ronser

Answer (score 0):

this is your query

```
for ($y=1;$y=1201;$y++)
{
$x = 1;

$query1 = "$conn, SELECT adlink, key  FROM usedcars WHERE key = $x";

$query2 = "$conn, INSERT INTO usedcars (adtext), VALUES ($final_text) WHERE key = $x";

$link_result = mysqli_query($query1);

$text_holder = file_get_contents($link_result);
$final_text = parse_array($text_holder, "postingBody", "<!-- .posting -->");

mysqli_query($query2);
echo "<font size='18' color='#FFFF00'>Placing text from $link_result into database</font><br>"; 
$x++;
}
```

My suggested query

```
 $x = 1;//put it before loop, every loop this $x will become one and the incrementation doesn't take effect
for ($y=1;$y=1201;$y++)
{


$query1 = "$conn, SELECT adlink, key  FROM usedcars WHERE key = $x";

$query2 = "$conn, INSERT INTO usedcars (adtext), VALUES ($final_text) ";//remove your where

$link_result = mysqli_query($query1);

$text_holder = file_get_contents($link_result);
$final_text = parse_array($text_holder, "postingBody", "<!-- .posting -->");

mysqli_query($query2);
echo "<font size='18' color='#FFFF00'>Placing text from $link_result into database</font><br>"; 
$x++;
}
```

Comment: I thought was an awesome idea! Unfortunately, I still get the same error when I did that. Thanks